# could not load library "libdl.so.2"

Tags: android, java-native-interface, native

I have been trying to use linux compiled prebuilt shared library with my android jni application, but when i try to run the application it gives following error:

04-16 19:09:13.633: E/dalvikvm(11810): dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.lXXXX.XXXX.connect-2/libXXX_embedded_shared.so") failed: Cannot load library: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1636): **could not load library "libdl.so.2"** needed by "libXXX_embedded_shared.so"; caused by load_library(linker.cpp:746): library "libdl.so.2" not found

i could not find libdl.so.2 in android/system/lib but there is a library libdl.so which i tried to load but it still did not resolve the dependency.

Can you please point me what i am missing here?

Comment: Try symlinking libdl.so.2 to libdl.so and see if that fixes the issue.  I am assuming the prebuilt linux library you are talking about is really a prebuilt android library that has been compiled for the correct arm architecture you are working on.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I already tried symlinking libdl.so to libdl.so.2 and it did not resolve the issue. Could you think of anything else which i can try?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do this.

Android and a normal linux have vastly different userspaces, in particular they use entirely different C libraries and associated incompatible dynamic linkers.

The very desire for a versioned library name (the .so.2 - something Android doesn't currently do) is indicative that this library was not build for Android.

**You need to rebuild all your libraries using the android ndk** either by creating and Android.mk and similar files to drive the normal ndk build system, or by using the ndk utility for generating a "stand alone toolchain" and pointing your project's build system at the resulting android-targeted gcc, ld, etc.

Some people have managed to use normal linux userspace components on rooted devices by putting a whole minimal install of debian-arm or similar in a chroot, but that requires root to set up and would not be linkable from an application process by jni anyway.  Your application process is already deeply tied to Android's C library so you can't really substitute another.